# Catch the timeout exception only

Tags: coldfusion

I have some handling logic for timeout exception only. Can I specify some type for `cfcatch` tag, which allow it to catch only timeout?
Right now I'm catching all exceptions and looking for "time limit" in `cfcatch.message`. It looks awful. Also my current code can catch some custom exception with "time limit" in message, which is not actually "timeout".

Comment: I could be wrong, but the way timeouts work is that ColdFusion doesn't actually throw the error until it arrives at the next thing on it's to do list. So, if you are stuck in a query that takes 8 minutes and your timeout is 1 minute, not until the query comes back and it tries the next thing will the timeout fire. You could capture this in the global onError in application.cfc. This is why low timeouts might not save you from a crash.

Comment: what kind of time out are you looking for... is it from a database or from some other type of routine?

Comment: A lot of routine, which includes several tough query, but is it really matter? I just wanna stop processing when timeout is occurred and make some logs about what has been already done.

Comment: Did you try this - cfcatch.StackTrace.indexof(javacast("string","coldfusion.runtime.RequestTimedOutException")) EQ 0 ? This will tell you if the exception is of origin 'Time out'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ugh, found it. `<cfcatch type="coldfusion.runtime.RequestTimedOutException">` Works perfectly. I can swear that I tried this before. Don't know how I missed that this is works. So stupid.

Comment: Yeah. His comment force me to try it again.

Comment: Note that you should add a `<cfsetting requesttimeout="#something_longer_than_the_original_timeout#">` as the first thing in that `cfcatch`, or you run the risk of immediately timing out again.